# Input state is stuck HIGH when function called using input also uses same input to call another function

Tags: button, input, loop, functions

I'm writing a choose-your-own-adventure style project for a class project. My Arduino Uno is set up with a 16-digit LCD display and two pushbuttons with pulldown resistors. I'm wanting each function to display text on the LCD and then take two user inputs, Yes or No, from the pushbuttons, and then call another function respective of which input is pressed. Each successive function will also take the two inputs to then call the next function in the series, and so on.

My issue is that after the first time a pushbutton is pressed, its state does not change. When `question1()` is called, and the user presses `button1`, `question2` is called. However, the function runs and never waits for user input, and `question4` is called right away because the state of `button1` seemingly stays `HIGH` after the first time it is pressed.

What am I missing? Is there a better way to be gathering the user input? My pushbuttons are properly wired with the resistor pulling down to ground so my issue must be with my code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
void loop()
{
  question1();
}

void question1()
{ 
  button1State = digitalRead(9);
  button2State = digitalRead(8);
  if (q1 == false)
  {
    text1();
  }

  if (button1State == HIGH)
  {
    question2();
  }

  if (button2State == HIGH)
  {
    question3();
  }
}

void question2()
{ 
  button1State = digitalRead(9);
  button2State = digitalRead(8);
  if (q2 == false)
  {
    text2();
  }

  if (button1State == HIGH)
  {
    question4();
  }

  if (button2State == HIGH)
  {
    question5();
  }
}
```

Comment: You're reading the (physical) button states in one location, inside `loop()` with `button1State = digitalRead(9); ...`. Once you call `question1()` from `loop()`, the values of `buttonState1` and `buttonState2` are fixed and will not change until your code returns to `loop()` to re-read the physical button state into `buttonState1` and `buttonState2`.

Comment: I was reading the button state at the beginning of each function and that wasn't seeming to do anything. Let me retry that though, thank you

Comment: Yeah the behavior is still the same. Since the state of the button is the condition of my `if` statement, perhaps that's what is holding this up?

Comment: think about this .... how do you detect two presses of one button?

Comment: @jsotola Yeah that's kind of what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: what is the sequence of events when you press a button twice?

Comment: If it's pressed twice nothing should happen unless the `textX()` function has ran, at which time it's time for user input again and the button press call the next function

Comment: You have to wait for the button to be released. Currently you wait for a button to be pressed in question1, which is fine. Once a button1 is pressed you go to question2, but since the button is still pressed it immediately goes on to question 4.

Comment: Do you suggest using the state of the button to assign a value to a variable, and then using that variable to call the respective function?

Comment: You want to count each button press once. So you don't want to look for the button pin being HIGH (as it will stay high for quite some time, like tens of milliseconds, ages for a microcontroller), you want to look for the transition from LOW to HIGH. Also you need to consider the button bounce, thus you need debouncing (you can google that). I suggest you have a look at the [Bounce2 library](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2), which will help a lot with reading mechanical buttons. Try the examples to understand, how the library is used

Comment: [This answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/74803/read-state-from-button-to-check-if-clicked) might also help you. There are sure many more questions about reading buttons on this site. You can just search for them.

Comment: reading a button is not so simple as it seams. and for multiple buttons and long press detection etc, the code in sketch gets complicated. I use a library. Bounce2 maintained by Thomas O Fredericks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There needs to be a `delay()` after the button state is read to allow time for it to return `LOW`, dumba**.

You already have enough `delay()` in your `textN()` functions, just check the button state *after* calling that function, not before. Code should be as follows:

```
void loop()
{
  question1();
}

void question1()
{ 
  if (q1 == false)
  {
    text1();
  }

  button1State = digitalRead(9);
  button2State = digitalRead(8);

  if (button1State == HIGH)
  {
    question2();
  }

  if (button2State == HIGH)
  {
    question3();
  }
}

void question2()
{ 
  if (q2 == false)
  {
    text2();
  }

  button1State = digitalRead(9);
  button2State = digitalRead(8);

  if (button1State == HIGH)
  {
    question4();
  }

  if (button2State == HIGH)
  {
    question5();
  }
}
```

This solves the issue completely.